# thread id of dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way to find the thread id that is associated with 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any block evaluated on the main queue will evaluate on the thread it is associated with, so you can get the ID of that thread by asking what thread such a block is evaluating on:

```
#import <mach/mach_init.h>

__block mach_port_t mainThreadID;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mainThreadID = mach_thread_self();
});
```

(A `mach_port_t` is really just an unsigned int.)